# What are the possible causes of a pending request to Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, http, firebase, websocket, firebase-realtime-database

I have a get request to Firebase. The network response is 101. The time tab in chrome dev tools is saying 'not completed'. The frames tab shows that the data has been retrieved, however, since the request hasn't completed, the data is apparently not available to consume?

> What are the possible causes of the pending request to Firebase?

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["firebase"]);

app.controller("budgetCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("budget");
$scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
});

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="budgetCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="dat in data">
  <span>{{dat.amount}}</span>
</li>
```

From Mac Air, El Capitan, Chrome browser, Server:localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected and normal behavior. The Firebase Database client communicates with its server over a web socket. This connection is a long-lasting connection. The call essentially never "completes", since there may always be more data coming from the database. That's why you see a status 101 and `Pending` in your dev tools.